# Use query twice mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php

a simple

```
$stuff = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

while($s = mysql_fetch_array($stuff)){
# ....
}

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($stuff)){
# ...
}
```

The last while() does not work. I have tried run foreach($stuff as $s) but then i get invalid array error.

How can i use the same query twice?

Comment: I think that you need to reset the array to the beginning before trying to reuse it as you've reached the end from the first result set.

Comment: please, stop using the outdate `mysql_*` functions an learn how to use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and prepared statements.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
$stuff = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

while($s = mysql_fetch_array($stuff)){
# ....
}
// add this line
mysql_data_seek( $stuff, 0 );

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($stuff)){
# ...
}
```

Should do the trick

Another way is of course to store your result in an array and reuse that

Comment: `mysql_data_seek( $stuff, 0);`
Here is the manual : [mysql_data_seek function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$stuff = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

while($s = mysql_fetch_array($stuff)){
# ....
}
mysql_data_seek($stuff, 0);
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($stuff)){
# ...
}
//ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php
```

Answer (score 0):

see the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

I guess it's because

> Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and **moves the internal data pointer ahead**.

I think moving data pointer with mysql_data_seek() would do the job
But i think this is not a good way, you should usually fetch data from database once and store them

Comment: yes I know that, I just wanted to say that it's better to use result once if possible

Answer (score 0):

If you user "foreach" instead of "while" you'll not have any problem and no need to mysqli_seek_data() :

```
//1st loop :
foreach($stuff as $row)
{
   echo $row['...'];
}
...
//2nd loop :
foreach($stuff as $row)
{
   echo $row['...'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simpler solution:

```
$slq = "SELECT * FROM users";

$stuff1 = mysql_query($slq);

while($s = mysql_fetch_array($stuff1)){
# ....
}

$stuff2 = mysql_query($slq);

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($stuff2)){
# ...
}
```

Assign the sql to a variable, and call mysql multiple times.

> no more mysql. use mysqli or pdo