# Result of mysql_query erased after first use?

Tags: php, mysql

I ran into a strange problem. I fixed it myself, but I am still curious why it occurs. I thought someone here on StackOverflow might be able to confirm it. I am using something like this in my project :

```
$users = mysql_query("select * from user where user_id = '$_GET[id]'") or die("Connection Error");
while($user = mysql_fetch_array($users))
$user_activated = $user['user_activated'];

// For testing purpose. This is not my original code but it's in the same sequence.
while($user = mysql_fetch_array($users))
echo "Test".
```

The echo "Test" never happens. Should there be any change happening to the $users array? Or is it automatically erased? I never came across anything quite like it. Can anyone provide some intuition into this?

Thank you!

Comment: Check out how [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) works

Comment: First, don't use mysql_* function, they're deprecated. Prefer using mysqli* or PDO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285557/use-query-twice-mysql-fetch-array

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: mysql_fetch_array fetches the next row from the database. Since the while loop right above looped through any possible rows, there aren't any left.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: you have to reset the current record pointer using `mysql_data_seek`

Comment: I'm so tired of `mysql_` warning comments

Comment: @jterry I'm so tired of people not reading documentation, but it's par for the course it'd seem.

Comment: As important as it may be to stop using mysql_ functions please use BRACES for your while loops and anywhere else that they should go. eg: while(){ //this will make life so much easier }

Comment: @BenM totally agreed. I feel like it's _so_ beaten at this point (by all of us) that SO should just have a standard header at the top of all MySQL-related questions with that comment :)

Comment: With two lines of code you've managed to create a [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) because you haven't [properly escaped your data](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Things like `$_GET[id]` should **never** be directly in your query string. Please, before you write any more SQL interfacing code at all, you must read up on these things.

Comment: @all Thank you for the quick comments and answers! This is plethora of information! I know mysql_query has some huge problems, but this is a small project so I simply used it. The PDO is great though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an internal pointer that keeps track of where you are in the resource as you're fetching rows.  Once you've made it to the end, you'd have to use `mysql_data_seek()` to get back to the beginning and be able to look through fetching again.

However, if you're going to need to pull the data out again, your best bet would be to store it in an array your first time, like so:

```
while($user = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
    $users_array[] = $user;
}
```

Then you can look through the `$users` array all you'd like without having to re-fetch from the resource.

On a side note, you should switch to PDO as well.  In addition to being not deprecated, you'll also have access to the `fetchAll()` method.

Comment: I can see no logical reason why the OP would need to do this in two separate `while` loops in the first place.  Also, that'll likely throw an error after the first iteration (I haven't tested it, though), since you're trying to use a Resource ID as an array of `$user` vars.

Comment: @BenM: Because the data may be needed in two separate locations in the script outside of a single loop. You're right about the error, I didn't pay attention to my naming conventions.. will fix.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have consumed a result set from `mysql_` then the pointer is at t he end of the recordset. when you ask an iterator to consume it again since the point is at the end of the results there is no iteration that occurs. to reset the pointer at the begining of the results set use

```
mysql_data_seek($rs, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

the records are not being deleted but mysql_fetch_array uses a pointer and iterates it, you can reset the pointer to initial result by using mysql_data_seek like this:

```
$users = mysql_query("select * from user where user_id = '$_GET[id]'") or die("Connection Error");
while($user = mysql_fetch_array($users))
$user_activated = $user['user_activated'];
// reset the pointer
mysql_data_seek($users,0) 

// For testing purpose. This is not my original code but it's in the same sequence.
while($user = mysql_fetch_array($users))
echo "Test".
```

Comment: You can't just leave that gigantic SQL injection bug in there without even saying anything. Seriously?